# Add Facebook SDK to Android Studio OFFLINE mode

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

My application is currently on the PlayStore.

Now I want to implement some social improvements like Facebook Share and others.

But I´m OFFLINE and based on Facebook docs I have to add some gradle dependencies. Looking over there I see some guides but anyone is complete or easy to understand.

I have the facebook-android-sdk-4.27.0.zip file and facebook-android-sdk-4.24.0.aar downloaded from a previous connection.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, here are the steps to import the .aar:

1. Right click on your project and select **"Open Module Settings"**.

[image: Open module settings]

2. Click the **"+"** button in the top left corner of window to add a new module.

[image: Add new module]

3. Select **"Import .JAR or .AAR Package"** and click the **"Next"** button.

[image: Import AAR]

4. Find the AAR file using the ellipsis button **"..."** beside the "File name" field.

[image: Find AAR file]

5. Keep the app's module selected and click on the **Dependencies** pane to add the new module as a dependency.

[image: Dependencies pane]

6. Use the **"+"** button of the dependencies screen and select **"Module dependency"**.

[image: Add module dependency]

7. Select the module and click **"OK"**.

[image: Choose module]

Comment: Wow, awesome answer! In two days a make a bounty and assign to you!

Comment: OK, I did it, but I got the error telling me that minSdkVersion must be 15 and my app is currently in 11. Is there a way to override this or simply use the SDK in the minimal SDK condition?

Comment: Why don't you just change your minSdk to 15?

Comment: Yes, I'll do that. Thanks!